# Select Row with MAX value while using another GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm brand new to learning SQL, so my apologies in advance is my question is elementary.

What I'm looking to do is display a column that would tell me the country with the highest and lowest values, respectively, of percent_aged_over_60 within already distinguished groups of "old_country" and "young_country":

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN percent_aged_over_60 >= 10 THEN "old_country"
        WHEN percent_aged_over_60 < 10 THEN "young_country"
        ELSE "error"
    END AS "oldness",
COUNT(*)
FROM countries_by_population
    GROUP BY oldness;
```

In other words, I'm looking to add a column that will tell me the name of the country with MAX(percent_aged_over_60) for "old_country" and the MIN(percent_aged_over_60) for "young_country".

While I'm sure this is easiest to do as two separate queries, I would like to do this within the same query.

As such, I'm looking for a result that produces three columns - oldness, count(*) and country.

Comment: If you're just showing one old country and one young country, what is `COUNT(*)` for?

Comment: True. Perhaps it's easier to just do the MAX from each

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
select t.country,t.oldness,count(*) from
(SELECT
 CASE
        WHEN percent_aged_over_60 >= 10 THEN "old_country"
        WHEN percent_aged_over_60 < 10 THEN "young_country"
        ELSE "error"
 END AS oldness
 , country
  ,*
 FROM countries_by_population) as t
 GROUP BY t.oldness,t.country;
```

Comment: What is the "t.____" for?

Comment: @dlilienfeld for better understanding of the query. you may safely omit them.

Comment: @dlilienfeld A bit above you can see `(an entire query) as t`. This means that the result of that query will be used as a temporary table, named `t`. `t.oldness` and `t.country` are columns in this temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the minimum and maximum percentages, then join this with the table to get the countries that match them.

```
SELECT country,
        CASE
            WHEN percent_aged_over_60 >= 10 THEN "old_country"
            ELSE "young_country"
        END AS oldness,
        percent_aged_over_60
FROM countries_by_population
JOIN (SELECT MAX(percent_aged_over_60) AS max_pct, MIN(percent_aged_over_60) AS min_pct
      FROM countries_by_population) AS x
ON percent_aged_over_60 >= 10 AND percent_aged_over_60 = max_pct
    OR percent_aged_over_60 < 10 AND percent_aged_over_60 = min_pct
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecd39/5)

Comment: Isn't a GROUP BY necessary before a HAVING clause?

Comment: Not if you want the aggregate function to apply to the entire result set.

Comment: I've corrected the answer. I needed to do the MAX and MIN in a subquery.